# How to pass JsonWebToken x-access-token through reactjs while using API?

Tags: reactjs, api, jwt

How do I pass dynamic JWT x-access-token while using an API with react? I know how to use the API using fetch method.

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://example.com/api/admin/dailyPosts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        postCount: response
      })
    })
  }
```

While consoling this.state.postCount, I get an empty array as no token is provided. So how do I pass the dynamic token to this API?

Comment: How does your server-side look like? Are you using something like express or passport.js?

Comment: What does this have to do with React?

Comment: No, I am not using express or passport. I am simply working on the create-react-app module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the token from API or generated, set it as cookie to the browser like

```
import { Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
Cookies.set(token, auth_token_here, {path: '/'});
```

Set get the cookie from the browser and set header object with the token in the request method like

```
import { Cookies } from 'react-cookie';

componentDidMount(){
    let auth_token = Cookies.get(token)
    let header_obj = {'Authorization': auth_token};
    fetch(url, { headers : header_obj}).then();
}
```

Assuming you have the token stored in the browser or is available as props from redux

Comment: Akhilesh, thank you for the answer. Actually, I don't know how to store the token in storage. If you can help, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: i used react-cookie in my project https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie. Edited the answer using react-cookie.